# Gradually change colour of polygon with gganimate

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I'm trying to create an animation where an object is drawn whilst gradually changing its colour. For illustrative purposes assume that the object I want to draw is a circle.

**What I have so far**

I create a dataset that contains the coordinates of my circle, a `time` variable and a `alpha` variable for gradually changing the colour:

```
t = seq(-pi, pi, length.out = 30)
df <- data.frame(
  x = sin(t), 
  y = cos(t), 
  time = 1:30, 
  alpha = seq(0.1, 1, length.out = 30)
)
```

Then I use `transition_reveal()` from {gganimate} to make the animation:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_path() +
  geom_polygon(aes(alpha = alpha), fill = 'grey30') +
  coord_fixed() +
  scale_alpha_identity() +
  transition_reveal(time)
```

Which yields the following animation:

[image: gif that draws a circle]

The circle is drawn sequentially (which is what I want), but the colour of the polygon does not change. It appears that only the first value of `df$alpha` is used for the whole animation.

**My question is thus** how can I change this animation such that the circle is still drawn sequentially **AND** the colour of the polygon gradually becomes greyer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There may be an easier way to do this, but with a bit of data manipulation you can do it via `transition_states`:

```r
df$frame <- 1

df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(seq(nrow(df)), function(i) {
  df$frame <- i
  df$alpha <- seq(0.1, 1, length = 30)[i]
  df[1:i,]
  }
))

df <- df[df$frame > 2,]

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_path() +
  geom_polygon(aes(alpha = alpha), fill = 'grey30') +
  coord_fixed() +
  scale_alpha_identity() +
  transition_states(frame)
```

[image]